# asp.net listbox problem

Tags: asp.net, listbox, selectedindexchanged

foreach (Book b in o.list)
    {
      ListBox_Items.Items.Add(b.Title);
    }

After I do this, the titles are now showing up in the listbox.

When I make a selection (Single Mode), ListBox_Items (Screen) is highlighting the row selected, but event `SelectedIndexChanged` is not triggering.

```
protected void ListBox_Items_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int i = ListBox_Items.SelectedIndex;
}

ID="ListBox_Items" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Width="400px" Rows="25" onselectedindexchanged="ListBox_Items_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

Any ideas ?

Michael

Edit 1 : Thanks to everyone for helping out.  Got it to work now.  Anyway, I had to turn on EnableViewState to True too.  Because I have a "Remove" button to remove items from the listbox control, if EnableViewState is False, whenever I clicked the Remove button, the listbox becomes empty again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `AutoPostBack="True"` in your aspx tag

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything to make the page post back to the server?

You  may need either a submit button, or you can add the property AutoPostBack="true" to your ListBox control.

See this MSDN Article for more information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox_Items" 
             runat="server" 
             EnableViewState="False" 
             Width="400px" 
             Rows="25" 
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox_Items_SelectedIndexChanged"
             AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: hi ian, really appreciate your help